# jQuery. How to stop repeated action once it happened?

Tags: jquery

I have an action that happens every 1 second:

```
(function(){
  $('.testme').jClever();
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})()
```

How can I stop it once it happened?

UPDATED: .testme comes from xmlhttpPost action and I can't get it work other way.

Comment: If you want to call `$('.testme').jClever();` only once, why do you include `setTimeout` at all?

Comment: Your code is wrapped in self-invoking function and then inside `setTimeout` is used in conjuction with function name which means it will keep on repeating, similar to `setInterval` but improved version.

Comment: .testme comes from xmlhttpPost action and I can't get it work other way.

Comment: Then call `$('.testme').jClever();` in the success callback of your Ajax request, i.e. once you added the new element(s) to the DOM.

Comment: <input name="send_button" type="button" value="send"  onClick="xmlhttpPost('response.php', 'MyForm', 'MyResult', '<img src=busy.gif>'); return false;"> is not the final point of request, .testme appears after php function. @FelixKling

Comment: Well, I don't know what `xmlhttpPost` is doing or how it works. You can definitely solve this properly though if you use jQuery's `$.post` function. Maybe `xmlhttpPost` accepts a callback to be executed after the call finished.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use clearTimeout() to stop setTimeout(), eg:

```
var clr = null;
(function(){
  $('.testme').jClever();
  clr = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})()

// assuming that arguments.callee is a function named foo
function foo() {
    clearTimeout(clr);
}
```

Comment: `arguments.callee` always refers to the function itself.